# Rotate all Textures

Tags: texturing, scripting, uv

I have this huge City and i want every texture to be rotated properly without manually going into UV-Mode and rotating every Texture-Face, is there a way to do this automatically?

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: Red circled Face is the way i want it.]

Comment: There is no way for Blender to know in which direction you want to have the textures on a face, so I guess the answer is "No, there is no way to do that automatically".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I managed to do it for my case, ill just post the script here:
(the code is pretty bad i know)

```
obj = context.active_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()
bm.faces.layers.tex.verify()  # currently blender needs both layers.
print("start of uv rotation")
# adjust UVs
for f in bm.faces:
    bigZ = -1000
    bigZindex = 0
    bigZ2 = -1000
    bigZindex2 = 0
    needsrotate = False
    #for i in f.verts:

    for l in f.loops:


        if bigZ <= l.vert.co.z:
            bigZ2 = bigZ
            bigZ = l.vert.co.z
            bigZindex2 = bigZindex
            bigZindex = l.index
        elif bigZ > l.vert.co.z > bigZ2:
            bigZ2 = l.vert.co.z
            bigZindex2 = l.index

    for l in f.loops:

        if bigZindex == l.index or bigZindex2 == l.index:
            #print("yes")
            if (l[uv_layer].uv.x == 1 and l[uv_layer].uv.y == 0):
                needsrotate = True
                #print("needsrotate")

    if needsrotate:            
        for l in f.loops:
            if l[uv_layer].uv.x == 0 and l[uv_layer].uv.y == 0:
                l[uv_layer].uv.x = 0
                l[uv_layer].uv.y = 1
                print("0.0 changed to 1.0")

            elif l[uv_layer].uv.x == 0 and l[uv_layer].uv.y == 1:
                l[uv_layer].uv.x = 1
                l[uv_layer].uv.y = 1
                print("0.1 changed to 0.0")

            elif l[uv_layer].uv.x == 1 and l[uv_layer].uv.y == 1:
                l[uv_layer].uv.x = 1
                l[uv_layer].uv.y = 0
                print("1.1 changed to 0.1")

            elif l[uv_layer].uv.x == 1 and l[uv_layer].uv.y == 0:
                l[uv_layer].uv.x = 0
                l[uv_layer].uv.y = 0
                print("1.0 changed to 1.1")


bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```